# Extraer promedio de resultados en Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql

espero esten bien, resulta que tengo un problemita, necesito extraer un promedio de cierta data en postgres pero tengo una duda y no se como aplicarla.
Tengo los datos ya estraidos pero quiero realizar un promedio de estas filas (hora, minutos, segundos) y al final realizar un agrupamientos, en este caso son tiempos de movimientos de actividad.
La verdad ya me hice bola y me gustaria que algun samaritano me de una mano.

la consulta que tengo es esta.

```
SELECT to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'HH24') AS "Hour",
to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'MI') as "Minutes",to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'SS') AS "Seconds"
FROM plre."EntryTrips" ext         
WHERE "ID_LANE" = '6291713'
AND ext."Timestamptrip" <= now()::date - 6
AND ext."Timestamptrip" 
IN (SELECT DISTINCT "Timestamptrip" FROM plre."EntryTrips" WHERE "ID_LANE" = '6291713' AND "Timestamptrip" <= now()::date - 6 
ORDER BY "Timestamptrip" DESC LIMIT 15) 
GROUP BY "Timestamptrip" ORDER BY ext."Timestamptrip" DESC;
```

Ahora bien, de esto obtengo este resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, resulta que de ahi necesito agrupar cada columna y realizar un promedio de hora y minutos, bueno, en el caso de las horas de momento no aplica porque seria la misma hora pero si aplica para los minutos y segundos.
No se si sera mejor realizar un promedio global de minutos por hora de los movimientos y asi sacarlo por hora.

Espero me ayuden hehe y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Con publicar tu solución en la zona de respuestas alcanza, no hace falta colocarlo en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arriba he colocado la respuesta pero la vulevo a incluir para aquellos que tengan alguna consulta similar.

```
        WITH intervals AS (
            SELECT to_char("Timestamptrip", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS fecha,to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'HH24') AS horas, to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'MI') AS minutos,
            to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'SS') AS segundos
            FROM plre."EntryTrips" ext         
                WHERE "ID_LANE" = '6291713'
                AND ext."Timestamptrip" <= now()::date - 6
                AND ext."Timestamptrip" 
                IN (SELECT DISTINCT "Timestamptrip" FROM plre."EntryTrips" WHERE "ID_LANE" = '6291713' AND "Timestamptrip" <= now()::date - 6 
                ORDER BY "Timestamptrip" DESC LIMIT 15) 
                GROUP BY ext."Timestamptrip", to_char(ext."Timestamptrip",'HH24') ORDER BY ext."Timestamptrip" DESC
        ) SELECT /*to_char(to_timestamp(fecha,'DD Mon YYYY')) AS fecha , */
            to_char(AVG(to_number(horas,'999D9')),'999') AS horas , 
            to_char(avg(to_number(minutos,'999D9')),'999') AS minutes,
            to_char(AVG(to_number(segundos,'999D9')),'999') AS seconds FROM intervals;
```

Comment: En 24 horas recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check de la izquierda. De este modo colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por tu colaboración :D